# Eliminar filas segun su dia festivo

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucle-for, dataframe, datetime

esta es mi duda.

¿como puedo eliminar dias festivos de un dataframe?

son solo los dias de fiestas en este caso de Alemania.

Ya busque bastantes librerias y he realizado muchas pruebas pero ninguna con el resultado deseado

un ejemplo.

```
import holidays

holiday_list = []

for holiday in holidays.DE(years=[2022, 2023]).items():
    holiday_list.append(holiday)

hdf = pd.DataFrame(holiday_list, columns=["fecha", "holiday"])
```

y aparece como resultado esto:

```
      fecha         holiday

0   2022-01-01  Neujahr
1   2022-04-15  Karfreitag
2   2022-04-18  Ostermontag
3   2022-05-01  Erster Mai
4   2022-05-26  Christi Himmelfahrt
5   2022-06-06  Pfingstmontag
6   2022-10-03  Tag der Deutschen Einheit
7   2022-12-25  Erster Weihnachtstag
8   2022-12-26  Zweiter Weihnachtstag
9   2023-01-01  Neujahr
10  2023-04-07  Karfreitag
11  2023-04-10  Ostermontag
12  2023-05-01  Erster Mai
13  2023-05-18  Christi Himmelfahrt
14  2023-05-29  Pfingstmontag
15  2023-10-03  Tag der Deutschen Einheit
16  2023-12-25  Erster Weihnachtstag
17  2023-12-26  Zweiter Weihnachtstag
```

ahora tengo un dataframe bastante amplio que marcan incluso horas y minutos en el cual solo deseo eliminar estos dias de fiestas.

Ya he usado varios metodos como `loc np.where compare`, etc. Pero no he encontrado el resultado que deseo. que es tener un nuevo dataframe sin estas fechas.

siempre queda igual o me da error.

```
column1                latency

2022-10-03 00:00:00    138.176
2022-10-03 00:05:00    141.697
2022-10-03 00:10:00    140.996
2022-10-03 00:15:00    142.806
2022-10-03 00:20:00    142.948
                        ...   
2022-10-03 23:35:00    139.032
2022-10-03 23:40:00    142.426
2022-10-03 23:45:00    138.730
2022-10-03 23:50:00    136.399
2022-10-03 23:55:00    141.982
```

Muchas gracias por su cooperacion y comprencion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La magia está en asegurarse que la columna sea de tipo `datetime64` ya que de esa forma puedes utilizar el accesor [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) y comparar directamente con los días festivos.

Para seleccionar las filas del dataframe que no contengan los días festivos utilizas un simple [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) y lo inviertes (Niegas) con el símbolo `~`.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import holidays
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['2022-10-03 00:00:00', '2022-10-04 00:00:00', '2022-10-05 00:00:00'],
                   'latency': [1,2,3]})

# Convertir la columna a datetime64
df['column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column1'])

print(df.loc[~df['column1'].dt.date.isin(holidays.DE(years=[2022, 2023]))])
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
     column1  latency
1 2022-10-04        2
2 2022-10-05        3
```

Lo puedes asignar a una nueva variable en lugar de imprimirlo para crear un nuevo `dataframe` excluyendo las filas que no necesitas.

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, alguien ya me habia dado su opinion anteriormente con este metodo.
```
hols = holidays.CountryHoliday('DEU')
df['hols'] = pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda x: hols.get(x)).values
df['hols'] = df['hols'].astype('bool').astype('int')
df = df.loc[df["hols"] != 1]
```

Use el tuyo y me funciono perfectamente igual. Muchas gracias.